# OpenCV v3.1.0 with CRF-RNN

Tags: python, c++, opencv, caffe, crf

I'm building [CRFasRNN](https://github.com/torrvision/crfasrnn) which itself is based on caffe) after upgrading openCV to version 3.1.0 (the previous one was 2.4 I think). I keep getting errors like

```
io.cpp:(.text+0x11f8): undefined reference to `cv::imdecode(cv::_InputArray const&, int)'
```

during compilation, specifically when complining . This didn't happen the previous time I installed it. I built caffe and pycaffe (version 1.0.0.) without much complications, but the one that crf-rnn requires apparently has a problem with opencv 3.1.0. Installing pycaffe for crf-rnn alone doesn't work either. All paths to libraries seem to work fine, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I tried working something out with dependencies of opencv, but I keep getting  messages like

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libopencv-dev : Depends: libopencv-objdetect-dev (= 2.3.1-7) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-highgui-dev (= 2.3.1-7) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-calib3d-dev (= 2.3.1-7) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-features2d-dev (= 2.3.1-7) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-legacy-dev (= 2.3.1-7) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-contrib-dev (= 2.3.1-7) but it is not going to be installed
```

OpenCV alone works fine. Before this installation I had no problems.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `imdecode` is in opencv_imgcodecs in version 3.0. It seems that you're mixing OpenCV versions... that's not good :D

Comment: I got so much, thanks. In Makefile I've explicitly set OPENCV_VERSION := 3

Comment: But your dependencies are on version 2.3

Comment: Yeah I got that too. I'm not sure what to do about, as this version of opencv works fine, so I think dependecies are not a problem. It only happens with crf-rnn...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I solved the problem by copying code from Makefile in the Caffe installation to Makefile for caffe-crfrnn. By 'code' I mean bits related to opencv. In addition to OPENCV_VERSION := 3 in Makefile.config I added

```
USE_OPENCV ?= 1

ifeq ($(USE_OPENCV), 1)
        LIBRARIES += opencv_core opencv_highgui opencv_imgproc

        ifeq ($(OPENCV_VERSION), 3)
                LIBRARIES += opencv_imgcodecs
        endif
endif

# OpenCV
ifeq ($(USE_OPENCV), 1)
        COMMON_FLAGS += -DUSE_OPENCV
endif
```

An it worked!